# How do i use Blazor components in the code?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm trying to accomplish something like the code below but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
@page "/"

<div>@test</div>
@code {
[Parameter]
public string Animal { get; set; }

private BaseComponent test { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    switch (Animal)
    {
        case "Cat": test = <Cat>Fluffy</Cat>; break;
        case "Dog": test = <Dog>Woff</Dog>; break;
        default: test = <p>None</p>
    }
}
```

I also want to be able to put components in a dictionary like `new Dictionary<string, BaseComponent> { {"cat", <Cat>test</Cat> }}`

any ideas?

Comment: Look up RenderFragments: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/07/19/how-to-dynamically-build.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just have each component in you html wrapped in conditions that show or hide?

Comment: Because I will have hundreds of these components, cats and dogs were just an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with RenderFragments:

```
private Dictionary<string, RenderFragment> switcher 
  = new Dictionary<string, RenderFragment>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    {  "cat" , __builder => { <Cat> It's a Cat </Cat> } },
    {  "dog" , __builder => { <Dog> It's a Dog </Dog> } },

};
```

and then outside of @code,

```
@switcher["Cat"]
```

---

But if this is the best solution depends very much on the exact use-case, and how much flexibility is desired in using the `<Animal>` tags.

You could for instance replace the above with a `<ShowAnimal Animal="Cat" />` component and implement that with a (big) switch statement in the markup section.

Comment: Please notice that you can only do this in a `.razor` file. You can't do it in the code behind (`.razor.cs`)

Comment: Yes, this obviously depends on the razor compiler. In a partial class you would have to use `builder.OpenComponent(...)` kind of code. Which might be preferrable in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

### A dictionary of render fragments :

```
@_content

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Animal { get; set; }

    RenderFragment _content => Animal switch
    {
        "Cat" => @:@{ <Cat>Fluffy</Cat> } 
,
        "Dog" => @:@{ <Dog>Woff</Dog> } 
,
           _  => @:@{ <p>None</p> } 
    };

}
```

### Note:

Switch comma's currently must to be on the next line due to a parsing bug.